# How to hide charField widget and show only label of field in django forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm developing an application with django framework.

I have a model that has these fields :

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1, null=True, blank=True)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

#forms.py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ('title', 'text',)
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['title'].widget =  #what to put here ?
```

For  title field I want only to show the help_text in Italics and not the CharField Input. 
Do Django permit doing something like that ?

Comment: Er, why would you want to do that? What's the point of a field that only shows its label?

Comment: it's demanded by a customer.. he wants to show some texts in the form ..
so the form is formed by nullBooleansFields, multiselectFields and among them there are these information fields ..I asked the question because I'm rendering the whole form in the template and not writing it manually :/